# Error XLS0502 The 'WindowsFormsHost' type does not support direct content

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to use a winform control in WPF(I've not found good alternative).
The control is the be.hexbox from sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/files/hexbox/
So I Start a new solution VB.net WPF and add WindowsFormsIntegration.dll reference.
I also add reference to the control dll.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:Be.Windows.Forms;assembly=Be.Windows.Forms.HexBox"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
      
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="TEST1">

            <wf:HexBox x:Name="HX" />


        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

but I get this error:
Error XLS0502 The 'WindowsFormsHost' type does not support direct content.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't set a direct `Content` in a `WindowsFormsHost` element, you need to set the `Child` property instead.

Try this:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="TEST1">
    <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        <wf:HexBox x:Name="HX" />
    </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer, when according to Visual Studio, "The attachable property 'Child' was not found in the type 'WindowsFormsHost'"? I seem to remember `WindowsFormsHost` accepting content until recently when this weird behaviour has started manifesting itself, and now it seems to be a completely redundant control! I'm guessing they keep changing things?

Comment: @Logix "accepted" on Stack Overflow just means that the original author of question chose to mark this particular answer as "it solved my issue at the time I marked as accepted". And, as you can see, there were not many other answers to choose from ;). Don't hesitate to write a more elaborate one, that includes this content and more information if you think this can be improved / expanded / detailed / updated etc.. that can bring value for other potential readers! Only OP can change the "accepted" mark, but all other users can vote on it, once they have sufficient rep.

Comment: Yes you're right, well I posted a question of my own because I'm completely unable to get `WindowsFormsHost` to function, and it was downvoted 3 times and then immediately closed! Extremely rude of SO, they didn't even provide any reasoning or warning. So I'm pretty much done with this site, I suppose if anyone else runs into these problems they will be screwed. And sorry if it came across as me saying the answer is wrong for the OP, of course it isn't, it's just confusing because it's recent and must've worked for them but I'm being told completely different things by my IDE.

Comment: Keep in mind it's not "SO" as an entity, but _some_ SO users that downvoted you and/or closed the question (3 users can vote to close a question or one gold badge / moderator). But I get the feeling, "hardcore downvoting" is hard to withstand. If you want more understanding on the "rationale" for closing questions, you can have a look (or ask) at [meta]. (and there, downvotes are "free" and don't hurt reputation, just so you know). There was (and still is) a long-running debate and propositions on how to make Stack Overflow more "welcoming"

Answer (score 2):

The project must have a reference to **both**:

- WindowsFormsIntegration
- System.Window.Forms

In my experience you do not need to specify <WindowsFormsHost.Child> in XAML. This may be dependent on the version. I am currently using .NET Framework 4.8.